# how converting data from custom cell format in excel 2003 with PHPExcel

Tags: php, converters, phpexcel, number-formatting

I have simple excel(2003 .xls) file I'm reading. I'm using PHP Excel from codeplex, but some cells have custom format type `# ##0,00%`.
When I'm reading the file, I'm always getting a failed value`(110.2f%)`

Now I solved this case:

```
$workSheet->getStyle('G'.$line)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
            $turnover_str = $workSheet->getCell('G'.$line);
```

output in browser: `-0.22878905524141`

but I need this format: `-22,87`

I convert using this function:

```
function conv_to_percent($str){
    $str = (int)$str * 100;
    $str = number_format($str, 2, ',', '');
return $str;}
```

Output in browser all result is 100  example when `$str` value is `-0.22878905524141`:

But I have created a clean PHP for this function and working fine(I have only this function):

```
 print conv_to_percent("-0.22878905524141"); //output: -22,88
```

I tried `(int), floatval($str)` but problem is same.

What am I doing wrong?